# use of adjectives in different places

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Are there any difference between two use of adjective in diffrent places in two sentence below ? Does these sentences have different meaning or one of these is wrong?

> New house was sold at ten thousand dollars cheaper **price**.
>
> New house was sold **at price** ten thousand dollars cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentences have more problems than the word order.

However, concentrating on the good location for "price": in that sentence, the word "price" need not be used. It is not OK to use "price" and "cheaper" together.

Why? Because:

- products are cheap(er)
- prices are low(er)

and not:

- products are low(er)
- prices are cheap(er)

---

Two ways to write that sentence are:

> - The new house was sold ten thousand dollars cheaper.
> - The new house was sold at a price ten thousand dollars lower.

Of course, one should also tell that it was cheaper / lower compared to what? Previous price for the same house? Another house? Which another house? But that is outside the scope of this question.